# New Job Pay Schedule

Tags: salary, united-states, compensation

I recently got a new job at a small company and earn a salary rate. They pay on the 15th and 30th of each month however the HR employee explained to me that although the pay week ends on the 15th and 30th of each month, I won't get the check until almost 5 days later for those pay weeks. I am sure they will pay me but according to HR employee it allows them to compensate for any "outstanding balances". Although I'm sure there is not much I can do and honestly I don't like their pay schedule at all however my question is this normal?

Comment: "I don't like their pay schedule at all". <-- Fair enough to have this opinion. But ask yourself if this fact is enough reason for you to turn down the job offer.

Comment: @Brandin, I didn't turn down the offer. I am just use to getting paid the same day for the pay week or a few days later not almost a week later. This is all new to me.

Comment: In your Q you said you will get the check after no more than 5 days later. I would consider that "a few days later". Just think of it this way - you get paid on (say) the 19th and the 4th of each of month.

Answer (score 2):

It seems perfectly normal to me.  I've always worked at places that paid either weekly or bi-weekly; and they always paid 1 week after.  This gives time to sort out any problems like your forgetting to complete a timesheet, filling it out incorrectly (working on project X instead of Y, got sick and left early, etc).  It's much easier for bean counters to fix things before the money's gone out than after the fact.

If anything, I'm mildly surprised your payday is only offset 5 days instead of 7; which would give the bean counters a consistent 5 days to do their work, instead of 5 days some weeks and 3 days others.  Are you sure they meant 5 calendar days, not 5 working days?

Comment: My company's pay periods are 1st - 15th and 16th - end of month. We get paid on the 25th (or earlier if 25th is on a weekend) and the 10th (or earlier), so I get usually 7 working days after the end of the pay period.

Answer (score 1):

> is this normal?

Yes, its normal.

I've also worked for companies that paid twice per month - there's nothing odd or nefarious about that. I've also worked for companies that paid once per month, every other week, and a few other arrangements.

And every company I've ever worked for held the paycheck for some number of days after the end of the pay period. Usually, it was around 5 days to 1 week.

In my last company, we were paid on Fridays for the previous week and the week before that (so 7 days after the end of the pay period for many, and 5 days after the end of the pay period for those who worked on Sunday). Timesheets needed to be completed and approved by the end of the day on Tuesdays, so they actually turned them around fairly quickly.

Nothing unusual here at all.